# Table Conversion- Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, pivot, sqlplus

I have a table with this structure:

```
date  colname   value
----------------------------
date  col1name  col1's value  
date  col2name  col2's value  
date  col3name  col3's value
```

Now I need to convert it into this structure:

```
date col1name       col2name      col3name  
-----------------------------------------------
date col1's value   col2's value  col3's value
```

Is it possible?

Comment: @OMG Thanks for the editting, that's just what I am asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a pivot table:

```
  SELECT t.date,
         MAX(CASE WHEN t.colname = 'col1name' THEN t.value END) AS col1name,
         MAX(CASE WHEN t.colname = 'col2name' THEN t.value END) AS col2name,
         MAX(CASE WHEN t.colname = 'col3name' THEN t.value END) AS col3name
    FROM TABLE t
GROUP BY t.date
```

If you want to make it dynamic based on the colname value, you'll need to use [dynamic SQL](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm) because you need to get the list of colname values first before constructing the actual query.

Oracle didn't add PIVOT/UNPIVOT support until 11g.  The `CASE` expression is supported 9i+; prior to 9i you'd have to use DECODE...

Comment: Hi Ponies. Thanks for your reply. But it is not about order, it is about flatten the previous table. i.e. 'importing the data' in your answer, I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: @sarahTheButterFly: Updated when I saw you change the formatting.